# How to increase the each page height differently in UIscrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I Have four pages in single uiscrollView and pageing is enabled. Each page may have different height, I Tried to increase the content size of scrollview in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating delegate but it does't help me.

Can any one suggest how to increment contentsize of scrollview in each page differently?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible, the content size is the bounds of the scroll view, it is a rectangle, how could it change for each page? Why not scale the pages so they are the same size and use zooming?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that natively. What you can try however is to disable paging and do it manually.

There is a useful delegate method for that:

`-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset;`

This let's you set where the scrollView will end its scrolling.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
    float offsetY = floorf((*targetContentOffset).y);
    float yGoto = 0.0;

    // Find out, based on that offsetY in which page you are
    // and set yGoto accordingly to the start of that page
    // In the following example my pages are 320px each

    // I start by only allowing to go 1 page at a time, so I limit
    // how far the offsetY can be from the current scrollView offset

    if(offsetY > scrollView.contentOffset.y + 160){
        // Trying to scroll to more than 1 page after
        offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 160;
    }
    if(offsetY < scrollView.contentOffset.y - 160){
        // Trying to scroll to more than 1 page before
        offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y - 160;
    }
    if(offsetY < 0){
        // Trying to scroll to less than the first element
        // This is related to the elastic effect
        offsetY = 0;
    }
    if(offsetY > scrollView.contentSize.height-320){
        // Trying to scroll to more than the last element
        // This is related to the elastic effect
        offsetY = scrollView.contentSize.height - 1;
    }

    // Lock it to offsets that are multiples of 320
    yGoto = floorf(offsetY);
    if((int)offsetY % 320 > 160){
        int dif = ((int)offsetY % 320);
        yGoto = offsetY + 320 - dif;
    }else{
        int dif = ((int)offsetY % 320);
        yGoto = offsetY - dif;
    }

    yGoto = floorf(yGoto); // I keep doing this to take out non integer part
    scrollView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
    (*targetContentOffset) = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x,yGoto);
}
```

Hope it helps!